# REST search gives zero results to users with custom read group

Tags: 2013, search, sharepoint-on-prem, sharepoint-rest-api, security-trimming

I have two SharePoint groups that use custom permission levels. The first user group gives access to read specific content and access to SharePoint's APIs. This group does not have access to see system pages. The second group is for power users and they have more edit permission and can see system pages. They also have everything the user group would have.

The search service account is in the user group which gives it read access to crawl the content. Power users are able to search and see the results. Regular user however are not getting any results when they run a search.

If the search service account had the same permission as the regular users and was able to crawl the content I would not expect security trimming to restrict access to the users. I am expecting results to come from a custom list that does not inherit permissions. Any idea how I can troubleshoot this problem?

Comment: Hi @Sam Nesbitt, welcome to SharePoint StackExchange :) , Could you please take a quick tour at https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tour to get informed badge! Thank you for your contribution :)

Comment: @M.Qassas thanks for the tip I read through the tutorial

Comment: I went to library where the content is getting its permissions and did a check permission on a sample user and the crawl account. I expected them to be the same but the crawl account had additional permissions on top of what a user had.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the missing permission was view application pages on the target list. Without this search will not return values.

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me as they did have View Items permission so I would not have expected security trimming to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you give the crawl account read access to everything. This is usually done through web application policy at the time that the Crawl Account is set in the SSA. The crawl account reads the ACL on the content and security trims the results based on the user making the query.

I would first ensure that the crawl account has read permissions then run a full crawl. Then I would log in as the limited read user and ensure that that account has access to the desired content. Then test search as that limited read user.